# VStack to the center of the screen

Tags: xcode, ipad, swiftui

I have to display like the following , used three VStacks to display it. However the login VStack is to the bottom of the screen. How to place it to the center of the screen and Google image to the top most of the screen

```
    struct Login: View {
       var body: some View {
      ZStack{
                CustomNavigationBar() // To diplay image
              VStack{
                LoginView(lgnvwmmodel: lgnvwmmodel) //To display Login View
                HelpView()
                }
            }
    }
    
    }



struct CustomNavigationBar: View{
    var body: some View{
        NavigationView{
        Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "google.png")!)
        } .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .padding(0)
    }
}

struct LoginView: View {
    
    @State private var emailId: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""
    @State var ntwrkShowAlert = false
    @State private var success = false
    @State var isModal:Bool = false
    @EnvironmentObject var DataGetting : DataStorage
    @ObservedObject var monitor = NetworkMonitor()
    @State private var isEmailValid : Bool   = true
    @State private var showingAlert = false
    @State var chngpasscode = false
    @State var btnClicked:CancelClicked = .none
    @State var showPopup = false
    @ObservedObject var lgnvwmmodel : LoginViewModel
   var body: some View {
       Text("Login")
            .font(.custom("OpenSans-Bold", size: 24))
            .padding(.top, 100)
        
        
        TextField("Email ID", text: $emailId)
            .onReceive(Just(emailId), perform: { _ in
                if emailId.count >= 50{
                    emailId = String(emailId.prefix(50))
                }
            })
            .modifier(customViewModifier(roundedCornes: 6,  textColor: .black))
            .frame(height: 100)
            .padding([.leading, .trailing], 100)

        
        SecureField("Password", text: $password)
            .onReceive(Just(password), perform: { _ in
                if password.count >= 50{
                    password = String(password.prefix(50))
                }
            })
            .modifier(customViewModifier(roundedCornes: 6,  textColor: .black))
            .frame(height: 100)
            .padding([.leading, .trailing], 100)
        
       
        
        
        Button(action: {
            
        }, label: {
            Text("Forgot Password ?")
                .underline()
                .frame( height: 40, alignment: .trailing)
                .padding(.leading, 320)
            
        })
        
        Button(action: {
     
            if(DataGetting.strEmail == ""){
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(self.emailId, forKey:"Email")
            }
            if((DataGetting.strPassword) == 0){
                UserDefaults.standard.setValue(self.password, forKey: "Password")
            }
            
            
            self.isModal = true



            if(monitor.status == .connected){
                self.ntwrkShowAlert = false
                lgnvwmmodel.dataStorage = DataGetting
            lgnvwmmodel.getUserIdDetails(emailId: emailId, password: password){ status in
                do {
                    if(status){
                       
                        success = true
                            
                    }
                }
            }
            
            }
            else{
                self.ntwrkShowAlert = true
                    
            }
            
            
        }, label: {
            Text("Sign In")
                .frame(width: 200, height: 30)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.red)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .font(.custom("OpenSans-Bold", size: 28))
            
        }).alert(isPresented: $ntwrkShowAlert){
      
      return Alert(title: Text("Please check your internet connection"), message: Text(""), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
          }

        
       
       
    }


}

struct HelpView: View{
    @State private var isAlert = false
    @State private var errorMessage: String = ""
    var body: some View{
    Button(action: {
        
    }, label: {
        Text("Help")
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 80)
            .background(Color.red)
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .font(.custom("OpenSans-Bold", size: 28))
    }).alert(isPresented: $isAlert){
        Alert(title: Text(self.errorMessage), message: Text(""), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
    }
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: First of all you don't need to wrap every view in own VStack, it is enough one at root. Second - looks like something pushes LoginView to bottom, probably inside `CustomNavigationBar`. Needed code of all involved views or minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Asperi I edited my code and it looks like the attached one. Can u plz chk

Comment: Sure, it is `NavigationView` consumes all available space. You need to rethink design (requirements are unclear) - probably move views inside NavigaitonView, probably use ZStack and hide unneeded, many possible variants.

Comment: @Asperi Tried like u said, used ZStack and VStack, now Help button shows below the loginView, it should be aligned to the bottom. I tried with Spacer() also, but not to the rescue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fixed simplified version (without models or button actions). I'm not sure why you wrapped the Google logo in a NavigationView? – so I skipped it as it causes layout issues.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            CustomNavigationBar()
            Spacer()
            LoginView()
            Spacer()
            HelpView()
        }
    }
}


struct CustomNavigationBar: View{
    var body: some View{
            Image("google")
    }
}


struct LoginView: View {
    
    @State private var emailId: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("Login")
            .font(.custom("OpenSans-Bold", size: 24))
        
        TextField("Email ID", text: $emailId)
            .padding().border(.black, width: 1)
            .frame(height: 100)
            .padding([.leading, .trailing], 100)
        
        
        SecureField("Password", text: $password)
            .padding().border(.black, width: 1)
            .frame(height: 100)
            .padding([.leading, .trailing], 100)
        
        Button(action: {
        }, label: {
            Text("Forgot Password ?")
                .underline()
                .frame( height: 40, alignment: .trailing)
                .padding(.leading, 320)
            
        })
        
        Button(action: {
        }, label: {
            Text("Sign In")
                .frame(width: 200, height: 30)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.red)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .font(.custom("OpenSans-Bold", size: 28))
            
        })
    }
}

struct HelpView: View{
    var body: some View{
        Button(action: {
        }, label: {
            Text("Help")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 80)
                .background(.red)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .font(.custom("OpenSans-Bold", size: 28))
        })
    }
}
```